# PDO Fatal Error Check Syntax

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

For some reason I'm gettin this error on the second line of included code:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'div='CA' WHERE vid='400373'' at line 1' in /home/stretch045/public_html/scripts/auth.php:12 Stack trace: #0 /home/stretch045/public_html/scripts/auth.php(12): PDO->prepare('UPDATE users SE...') #1 /home/stretch045/public_html/index.php(35): Auth->checkToken('94257b73ea4ed51...') #2 {main} thrown in /home/stretch045/public_html/scripts/auth.php on line 12

code

```
$conn = $this->db;
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET rating='".$xml->rating."', atc='".$xml->ratingatc."', pilot='".$xml->ratingpilot."', div='".$xml->division."' WHERE vid='".$xml->vid."'"); 
$stmt->execute();
if($stmt->rowCount()==0){
     $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (vid, fname, lname, rating, atc, pilot, div) VALUES (".$xml->vid.",".$xml->firstname.",".$xml->lastname.",".$xml->rating.",".$xml->ratingatc.",".$xml->ratingpilot.",".$xml->division.")"); 
     $stmt->exec($stmt);
     echo 'data inserted into db';
}
```

Comment: reserved word questions are often asked; voted to close as such

Comment: yeah @DrewPierce but an answer's been slipped in ;-) I'll post an answer for these, like 1 in 1000. I rarely do.

Comment: @DrewPierce si signore ;-) I don't "need" the points. No quota for this guy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`div` is a [reserved keyword in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) and needs to be escaped by backticks.

```
INSERT INTO users (vid, ..., `div`) VALUES (...)
```